# Centos 7 - cups-pdf postprocessing script running but no result

Tags: centos, cups

I got an issue using the postprocessing in cups-pdf.
The script is called as I can see in the log files, but nothing happens.

/var/log/cups/cups-pdf-myPrinter_log:

```
Thu Jun 15 10:07:11 2017  [DEBUG] postprocessing commandline built: /etc/cups/postprocessing/ppmyPrinter.sh /srv/samba/cups-pdf/myPrinter/user/000012198600001.pdf user@dom.local user
Thu Jun 15 10:07:11 2017  [DEBUG] postprocessing has finished: 32256
```

vim /etc/cups/cups-pdf-myPrinter.conf

```
PostProcessing /etc/cups/postprocessing/ppmyPrinter.sh
```

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 root lp  194 Jun 15 09:35 ppmyPrinter.sh`

vim /etc/cups/postprocessing/ppmyPrinter.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" >> /etc/cups/postprocessing/user
echo "$2" >> /etc/cups/postprocessing/user
echo "$3" >> /etc/cups/postprocessing/user
```

if I run the script `./ppmyPrinter.sh test1 test2 test3` it creates the file user with the content test1 test2 test3 but by calling from cups nothing happens.
I red, that on a debian based system (ubuntu) cups-pdf is watched by apparmor and I have to permit to execute the script, but on my CentOs 7 there is no apparmor running.

Could you give me a hint, where to look for this issue, are there som log-files where I can see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS you have to deal with SELinux instead of AppArmor, if this might be an issue. Check your SELinux status by `getenforce`. If it is `Enabled`, inspect the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` file.

Comment: # getenforce - Disabled
I also checked the audit files but nothing to see there, also if I tail the audit.log and create a print job. :(

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS there is another setting that causes the same symptoms. The post processing script runs as "nobody" user by default, so you must to add a line in the /etc/sudoers file to allow the script to run without prompting for a password:

nobody ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:/yourpath/yourscript.sh